# How can I browse a picture from iPhone picture library?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image

I am new in ios development. I am doing a photo cropper app.

I want to browse an image from the iPhone picture library by clicking browse button (that I added in my app) and load it to UIImageview that I placed in a view.

How can I browse the image ?.

Is it possible to browse the complete phone memory ? (Just like asp:FileUpload).

Is there any control available in iPhone to use just like asp:FileUpload ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Super easy to do!

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController     alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

and

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];

    // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
    //myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    // AND the original image works great
    //myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
    //UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [customImageView setImage:image]; 

    customImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
```

got this code from stackoverflow, didn't save the URL, sorry.

Comment: Thankx alot. It works. It really helped me alot. I was searching for this from the past two days. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

The whole file system is not available, if you're running a non-jailbroken phone. Neither are there filesystem browser controls (for the same reason), However, you can browse the user's photo library, or even take a photo with the camera using UIImagePickerController. Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html