# Monotouch - Browse for image in application

Tags: ios, ios5, xamarin.ios

As appears in the title, what control should I use to let the user do the following:

1. Browse for image in pictures folder in iphone to set it as background to `UIViewController`
2. Copy it to my background image folder .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I browse a picture from iPhone picture library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727160/how-can-i-browse-a-picture-from-iphone-picture-library)

Comment: Ok...that's nice but I was looking for monotouch equivalent..thanks though.

Comment: use MT's UIImagePickerControl - the language is different but the control and API's are the same

Comment: Yah , i will try that...thanks jason